# Sequentially execute SQL Procedures and stop in case of failue

Tags: sql, plsql

I have a multiple procedures which have to executed sequentially. And in case any procedure fails, all the procedures below shouldn't get executed.

Example, I have
`EXEC myProc1; EXEC myProc2; EXEC myProc3; EXEC myProc4;`

myProc1 got successfully executed and for some reason myProc2 failed and didn't get executed successfully. I don't want executor to proceed with myProc3 and myProc4.

Any suggestions on how this can be implemented?

Comment: have you tried sql exception handling at all?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're executing them a sqlplus script, correct me if I'm wrong. There are a couple of possibilities.

Use the `WHENEVER SQLERROR` clause at the beginning of your script. That specifies what action needs to be taken when any of the invoked sql or pl/sql commands error out.

In your case:

```
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT
EXEC myProc1; 
EXEC myProc2; 
EXEC myProc3; 
EXEC myProc4;
```

Another solution is to just wrap all the procedures in an anonymous pl/sql block. As soon as an error is raise the block will error out.

```
BEGIN
 myProc1;
 myProc2;
 myProc3;
 myProc4;
END;
```

The assumption for the 2 solutions above is that each of the procedures raise an exception (no EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL;) in case of error.

Comment: Let me try this out. Thank you.